# How to get along with a manager who loads the dice?

Tags: relationships

Our manager thinks other employees are competitors for his current position. He loads the dice against his subordinates. We're afraid to do our best in work. On the other hand, one whose performance is dismal will certainly be fired.

Comment: `He loads the dice against his subordinates.` for example?

Comment: It's time to look for a different employer then.

Comment: The manager isn't the boss. He thinks other employees are competitors for his current position. Subordinates who do their duties to the best of their ability may take underhand punishment. It's bothering me.

Answer (score 4):

Treat the workplace exactly as you would treat any other workplace.

This kind of manager can make it hard to take pride in your work but that doesn't mean you shouldn't try. You will feel better and be rewarded better.

(in other words: there isn't a quick fix, other than finding a new job)

Answer (score 2):

Play to win! Outshine him and take his job away from him.

I'm sorry to be so blunt. But an manager who discourages good work from his team is a fool.

Comment: This requires quite a bit of politicking in addition to outshining, a skill the OP may lack.